# How to add multple buttons from one activity to an a different to activity in android

Tags: java, android-intent, android-activity, gridview, android-mediaplayer

I would like for onClick to remain playing the sounds. However I want to have an activity with all my favorite sounds, therefore placing the respected sound in a "favorties" activity upon a long click. Also which it will play in the "favorties" activity and save the favorites.

```
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            player = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.sound1);
            player.start();
        }
    });

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            player = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.sound2);
            player.start();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use one activity and load different fragments depending on the user action.
This way your activity will act as a controller to the fragments and all of the buttons in those fragments will call to the same activity.

Look at the docs for the how to
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html

This is also a cleaner way to build your user interface within android applications.

Comment: So by doing that would I easily be able to make a "favorites" activities where it will hold all my favorite sounds. Also would I be able to adjust the "favorite" activity be being able to remove any respected sound upon selection

Comment: You don't need to make a new activity for that it can also be another fragment, that you load if the user wishes to see his favorites. You can add swipe movements to load between them similar to what google music app does...
Check the link that I gave, looking into the fragments part. it's the better way to construct your GUI. Don't only think about making new activities. activities should function as a controller go OOP

Comment: I'm still quite the novice with android programming and I have developed tabs using fragments. So from what you're sating it'll be relatively simple to code this and having it align as perfectly as well

Comment: Well everything is simple if you know how to.
I know most books don't cover fragments that well and don't even scratch what you can do with them. But stick to the google Doc's and google a lot.
Here is something to give you an idea of what you can do with fragments. and some sample code to play around with. [link](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip).

Comment: That's how I've learned is Google and YouTube which helped a lot. I'll definitely check that out and I appreciate the help